# React ESLint: inconsistent save format on WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, eslint, webstorm

I'm not sure what is happening but using the WebStorm editor saving the file will sometimes correctly execute `eslint --fix` and sometimes format using its own rules.

This is an example of what I'm encountering:

- Saving sometimes gives me this formatting, which causes errors since my ESLint does not follow that format:

[image]

- Saving other times will correctly re-format it following ESLint rules:

[image]

I'm on a React App using the `create-react-scripts`. I re-configured its ESLint with airbnb configuration. I already checked that 'Reformat on save' of WebStorm is disabled, I have only "Run `eslint --fix` on Save" active.

How can I fix this behaviour so that WebStorm will ALWAYS save formatting following the ESLint rules?

This is my `.eslintrc.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    'import/no-unresolved': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 'off',
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    'max-len': 'off',
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
    'react/no-this-in-sfc': 'off',
  },
};
```